# Weyl's criterion on unbounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Consider the following theorem.

***Theorem:*** Let $A$
be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Then$ λ \in σ(A) $ if, and only if there exists a sequence $ ({\psi_{n}})_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $  such that $\|\psi_{n}\|=1 $ for all $ n $ and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \|(A−\lambda)\psi_{n}\|\rightarrow 0. $$
This is a 'part' of the so-called Weyl's criterion.

***Question:*** is this result true in the case of an unbounded and a non-self-adjoint operator?

Comment: Weyl's Criterion stays true for unbounded selfadjoint operators, see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_spectrum). Since it is in fact usually formulated as a criterion for the essential spectrum, I don't think there is a generalization to non-selfadjoint operators.

Comment: It should be true for normal operators.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true of a bounded, non-self-adjoint operator. For example, consider the shift operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$:
$$
          S\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots\}=\{0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots\}.
$$
$0$ is in the spectrum of $S$ because $S$ is not surjective; indeed, $\{ 1,0,0,0,\cdots \}$ is not in the range of $S$ (in fact, it is orthogonal to the range.) However, there is no sequence $\{ w_n \}$ of unit vectors in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\|(S-0)w_n\|\rightarrow 0$, which is obvious because $\|Sw_n\|=\|w_n\|=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: +1. I have a question. Is the criterion true for normal operators? I guess it is. Indeed, the operator $S$ of this example is not normal.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : Post a new question concerning the case of a normal operator.